# AxisFault Read Timed Out

Tags: java, timeout, axis

I have a web service which does quantitative model checking and an Axis2 client which calls the web service. The web service can take a lot of time (more than a minute). The client works fine when the model is small and service takes less than 30 seconds. But when I call the web service with a larger model I get the [AxisFault exception](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/AxisFault.html) with the message "Read Timed Out". This happens about 30 seconds into the call. Is there a way I change this timeout time to a larger value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out myself. I used this command `stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(120000);`

Relevant info -

[_getServiceClient()](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/client/Stub.html#_getServiceClient%28%29)

[getOptions()](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/client/ServiceClient.html#getOptions%28%29)